# Create Directory with public read permissions in Java

Tags: java, file, directory, java-io

I want to create folders that are public read/ write permission. This will be required to be run on Unix later, which is why I added the Posix code, but currently I am developing on windows.

The code below tries to create a file that has write permission using f.setWriteable(). However the code outputs:

'creating file that is writeable false readable true'

The directory gets made, but without the writeable permission. , as writeable boolean check is false , the result of f.setWriteable.

I can do setWriteable on a file without any issues, but cannot seem to do it on a folder.

How can I create a folder with the suitable permission cross platform?

I assume it may be due to me using an absolute path, rather than a relative, but cannot find information on this.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermission;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class FileTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String path = "C:/home/1/";
        File f = new File( path );
        if ( !f.exists() )
        {

            boolean success = f.mkdirs();
            boolean writeable = f.setWritable( true, false );
            boolean readable = f.setReadable( true, false );
            System.out.println( "creating file that is writeable " + writeable + " readable " +
                readable );
            if ( !success )
            {
                System.out.println( "Folder Directory not found.{}" );
            }
            boolean isPosix = FileSystems.getDefault().supportedFileAttributeViews()
                .contains( "posix" );
            if ( isPosix )
            {
                // using PosixFilePermission to set file permissions
                Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = new HashSet<>();
                perms.add( PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ );
                perms.add( PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE );
                perms.add( PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ );
                perms.add( PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE );
                perms.add( PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ );
                perms.add( PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_WRITE );
                try
                {
                    Files.setPosixFilePermissions( Paths.get( path ), perms );
                    // if ( LOGGER.isDebugEnabled() )
                    // {
                    System.out.println( "Set Posix permissions" );
                    // }

                }
                catch ( IOException e )
                {
                    System.out.println( "Unable to set posix permissions" );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Windows doesn't have permissions the same way as Unix/POSIX. Generically files have one bit that prevents write, but no distinction between self/group/other, and no bits to control read or execute. For directories you can't even prevent write. For NTFS but not FAT you have ACLs which express much more detailed restrictions than POSIX, but they vary on different versions of Windows. In the source I have to hand (of early java8) windows/native for java_io_WinNTFileSystem_setPermission doesn't even try to deal with ACLs, it implements only one no-write bit and only on nondirectories.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Java7 then maybe this will be the answer: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html

Comment: Please include a summary of the answer provided in the linked material in case the link goes bad, is moved, or is otherwise changed.